# Injecting custom value in API URL in BAT CLI for Mulesoft

Tags: rest, api, automated-tests, functional-testing, mulesoft

I am using BAT CLI in Mulesoft to write functional API tests - https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-functional-monitoring/bat-bdd-reference.

I am trying to use a value obtained in the response of an API call in the URL for another subsequent API call.

```
import * from bat::BDD
import * from bat::Assertions
import * from bat::Mutable

var context = HashMap()
---
it ("capture a value from a API response") in [
    GET https://first.api.call/abc,
    execute [
            // This works
            context.set('myVal',$.response.body.myVal)
          ]
],
it ("use the value in the second API URL") in [
    // I am trying to inject the value obtained above in the URL below
    GET https://first.api.call/{context.get('myVal')}
    ....
]
```

Apparently I am not getting the syntax correct. `{context.get('myVal')}` does not work. I also tried `$({context.get('myVal')})`, `$(context.get('myVal'))` which also do not work.

Can anyone tell what the right syntax would be?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:
`GET https://first.api.call/$(context.get('myVal'))`

Cheers!